# Showing results of one column into two columns

Tags: sql, pivot-table

Select Participants from table will result in

```
Participants
-------
John
Nancy
Jem
Albert
Smith
Daniella
```

I want a query where the results shows

```
Player   Opponent
------   --------
John      Nancy
Jem       Albert
Smith     Daniella
```

A good sample for this question is the query used in generating single-elimination tournament pairings.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us how you attempted to solve this problem. That way, we are better able to help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functios.Just LEAD+ROW_NUMBER to get opponent and then get player with odd numbers

```
  SELECT player,Opponent FROM
 (
   SELECT player, Number, LEAD(player)OVER(ORDER BY Number)Opponent from
    (
       SELECT player, ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY player)Number FROM Table
    )X
 )Y
   WHERE Number % 2 <> 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much Olga Romantsova for your concern .. can you please review your answer based on my edited question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select min(player) as player, max(player) as opponent
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by player) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor( (seqnum - 1) / 2)
```

Comment: Guys I am really sorry I think my question was not clear enough .. I don't know why it posted like this although it showed correctly on my screen before posting .. the idea is when select participants from table the result is many rows showing the participants .. I put player1 player2 as an example

Comment: Think of them as names that has no numbers beside them .. the result of the query select participants from table is for example (first row John .. second row Edward .. third row Nancy .. fourth row Jem .. fifth row Daniela .. sixth row Mark) and I want the result as (first row John and opponent is Edward) (second row Nancy and opponent is Jem) ( third row Daniela and opponent is Mark)

Comment: Sorry again for this confusion .. I finally managed to correct the post and show it as it suppose to show

Comment: @user3208728 . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the first row, unless a column specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much Olga and Gordon for your contributions. I found the answer by Olga more close to what I need.

Thanks again all